# Wrap plain text mail in html

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, email-server, sendmail

we use Postfix as MTA to send our mails from our system. Unfortunately we have an old persistent system which we cannot change, which sends mails to our customers in plain text format. I would like to wrap these mails in HTML. I have tried to write an application in Golang using Milter to wrap and replace the body in HTML, but have not been successful yet. Is there by any chance a more elegant solution for this?

Greetings Pa0x43

Comment: The most elegant solution is to admit that a message that *needs* complex markup should not have been sent in the first place. Is there content? Then plain is king. - But Purely stuffing? Do not send it at all.

Comment: We're sending information emails for temporary work. So there are information about needed qualification, when, where etc. all in plain text. It not really needs markup, its just looks better with an minimal markup like logo etc.. The mail is getting sended to over 2000 recipients.

Comment: *HOW* does it sends emails?  1)  via SMTP connection to configurable host (and port)? 2) via executing "sendmail look alike" program (with configurable path to executed binary file)?

Comment: You could try alterMIME, but it is best fixed at the origin, and failing that using custom code as you've already tried and failed.

Comment: @AnFi its using a sendmail look alike. Actually its just the mail() function from PHP. Nothing special...

Comment: @symcbean i will give this a try. Maybe its just easier to wrap the text within the PHP function.

Comment: OMG???? "legacy application" is written in PHP and you tried to fix this by writing a milter in golang????

Comment: This system is from 2010 and not maintained anymore. Its not based on any kind of framework eg. symfony or laravel. Its just plain php. To change just the text to html i need to rework like 100 lines per file. Of course would i rewrite the function if its simplier than write a milter in golang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Rewriting/preprocessing emails send using sendmail programs

As I understand in your case you can use "sendmail preprocessor" program/script.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.sendmail-path

it will get email over its standard input andt should pass it to standard sendmail after rewriting. Make sure to return sendmail's exit code.

PHP mail uses "sendmail -t -i" (with optionally added "-f envelope_sender).
It means that recipients addresses are extracted from To:/Cc:/Bcc: Headers.

Comment: I went with this solution. Right now i can wrap plain text within html. Still need to work on the attachments etc.